# Holdem manager 2 HUD stats definition

Tags: poker-tools, holdem-manager, hud

When I use the live HUD statistics by holdem manager 2, I see numbers like this:

```
23 / 15 / 0 / 0
```

I understand that the first two numbers are **VPIP** and **PFR**, but what do the 3rd and 4th numbers mean and how can it be used to deduce a read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, for preflop play it goes like this:

**VPIP / PFR / 3B / F3**

Meaning:
1) **VPIP:** Voluntarily Put Money in Pot, i.e. how often a player raises & calls. The higher the stat, the looser the player
2) **PFR:** Preflop Raise. How often the player raises preflop. The bigger the gap between VPIP and PFR, the more passive the player is.
3) **3B:** 3-bet percentage preflop, how often the player re-raises. Self-explanatory. Around 3% means re-raising only with good hands (Big Pairs & AK and some AQ)
4) **F3:** Fold to 3-bet percentage (self-explanatory). Helps you if you want to steal from the original raiser by 3betting often.

Additional Popular Stats (for postflop game):
1) **AF:** Aggression factor of player (how often he raises, reraises in general). Normal values between 1 to 3.
2) **CB:** Continuation bet percentage : how often the player bets the flop when he is the initial bettor.
3) **WTSD%:** Went to ShowDown percentage: Indicates if player likes to call you down to the river often.

---

All these numbers are just indicators. Remember that you need a good sample of >200 hands to start extracting useful data. But, they can give you an idea of an opponent's personality in close spots if you manage to read them as you play (need to be fast!)